# Xamarin - Array math operations to display in ListView

Tags: c#, arrays, listview, xamarin

I've a ListView that display the elements of an array, each element must be multiplied for 9.

Here is my code:

```
   h = 0;

   Int32.TryParse(heightEditText.Text, out hArray[h++]);

   string[] hList = hArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, hList);
```

I tried to do the formula with another array to dispay in the ListView:

```
m[i++] = 9 * hArray[h++];
```

P.S: array is [++] because otherwise in the listview replaces each element with the subsequent ones

Comment: `string[] hList = hArray.Select(x => (x * 9).ToString()).ToArray();`

Comment: Works, so simple that I had not thought about it ¢_¢ Thanks